# Angle symbols in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, semantics

I will write a lot about Euclidean Geometry the next time. This means I need to denote angles.

The symbol we use in class looks like `\sphericalangle`, but I've just seen that there is an `\angle` symbol / command:

[image]

Now I have three questions:

1. What is the semantic difference of those three symbols? (And maybe other symbols you know for angles)
2. `\measuredangle` is quite long and I don't think that I will need more than one symbol for angles (it depends on your answer to question 1). So I would like to re-define `\angle` so that I get the symbol of `\measuredangle`. I think the way to do this would be

   ```
   \renewcommand{\angle}{\measuredangle}
   ```

is that correct? When I do this, is there any way to get the original symbol of `\angle`?

(Not part of my main question, but I hope to get some comments about this:
Is it a bad idea to use another symbol than `\angle`? How well-known is the difference of those symbols? (I know this is open, I just want to read what you think about it. I think semantics are important).)

Comment: To answer your last question: `let\OldAngle\angle` and _then_ `\let\angle\measuredangle` should do the trick. Then you can access the original `\angle` as `\OldAngle`.

Comment: +1 to Peter, and the other questions are not really LaTeX-related (in my opinion).

Comment: @SándorKazi: I think my question if there are more symbols for angles is LaTeX-related. Also, the question about the semantic difference. And the question if it's a bad idea to use another symbol than `\angle` ... well, I'll put that in brakets. This was not my main question.

Comment: The semantic difference is more likely a question of mathematical notation. I think the "is there more" is the same. One might use the letter "x" as an "angle symbol", this IS a question of what is common or what is not. Your question is good, but I think it's about general mathematics, not LaTeX.

Comment: @SándorKazi: I still think that the "is there more"-part is TeX-related, but maybe this is not suitable for tex.stackexchange (and stackexchange in general). Do you know a place where such open ended TeX / math question can be asked?

Comment: I would submit a "what notations are common" question on [math.SX](http://math.stackexchange.com/). You can also ask all your questions there. If you finally find the most suitable notation, then it can be a LaTeX question how to make it appear (if it's not one of the above).

Comment: @SándorKazi: Thanks for the advice. I've asked this part of the question on math.SX: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/640838/6876

Answer (score 9):

[Answer for 1]  I have a guess for your first question, but I think it is a reasonable guess.

`\sphericalangle AOB` = angle between two intersecting arcs on a sphere, specifically the angle between the two planes containing the arcs [There seems to be a distinction in notation where the center letter is O, not B]

`\measuredangle ABC` = the actual measured angle between points A and C at point B

`\angle ABC` = angle between points A and C at point B (the middle letter is the vertex) [I have also seen this used to define angles in Euclidean triangles].

[Answer for 2]  You could use `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand` and define your own new command that is shorter but distinct (e.g., `\mangle`).